# Access Custom Primary Keys

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

eI'd like to create custom primary keys in my Access database.

The database is going to be multi-user, so I need a method that ensures each key is unique even when multiple users are trying to add new records to the same tables.

The reason I need to create custom primary keys is because my database starts off an audit trail that goes in to another, external system that I have no control over.

This other system does however allow the use of a single 12-character length user-defined field for us to pass data of our choice through.

I'd like to use that user-defined field to record a 12-character code that has various abbreviations I can extrapolate later (e.g. first 2 characters relate to a department in our organisation, next 3 characters relate to a product and so on...)

From the reading I've done so far, custom keys in Access seems to be something of a minefield.

For my purposes though, I can kind of see at least a compromise in combining Access' autonumber field to essentially help build the primary key I want.

Here's what I was thinking:

The parts of the code that I would want to extrapolate later can be built by our users, so for example, if the Department was Human Resources, the first 2 characters could always be "HR".

Then lets say I let the AutoNumber in access run for a field in the same table in which my "HR" entry was populated... could I get a third field to automatically concatenate the 2 in the same table (not query)...? i.e. like this:

```
| Department | AutoNumber | CustomPrimaryKey |
|    HR      |     1      |        HR1       |
```

If that's something that can be done on some event in VBA, then that would be great (show me the code! :))

The second part would be whether I can get the autonumber to concatenate with leading zeros ensuring the "unique number" part of the custom primary key was between 99999 and 00001, i.e. occupying the same 5 character space like this:

```
| Department | AutoNumber | CustomPrimaryKey |
|    HR      |     1      |     HR00001      |
|    HR      |     2      |     HR00002      |
```

It is highly unlikely that I would need more than 100,000 entries.

I hope this is possible and safe!

Comment: Sorry - i'm a bit new to VBA, but imagine what I would want to do is store the concatenation of the Department & AutoNumber in a VBA variable and then push it through the form's textbox on some event for form... not sure what event is appropriate though. I can probably figure a way of getting the leading zeroes with `LEN` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather leave this as a comment than an answer as I don't think you're totally clear on what you need, but I'll try to answer as best as possible. Also, I'm not going to "Show you the code!" as you suggest as it teaches nothing.

In the first question of automatically concatenating the third field, it's really a question of how the fields are being populated.

If it's through form input, then you can concatenate all of the component fields into the key field during the update events of the controls those component fields are being populated. In VBA you can easily reference members of the record by accessing the form's recordset.

If you're populating the field through a file import where you already have import specs, then you would perform the import excluding your key field, then open the recordset of the table where you imported and iterate through the recordset. You can learn about ADO recordsets [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Again, I'm not just going to write the code because I don't really know what you need this for.

If you're populating the field through your own parser than I probably don't have to explain how to do this.

To your second question, you can easily right align a number in a string using the format() function. For example `format(2,"00000")` would yield "00002" and `format(210,"0000")` would yield "0210". You can also make the number of 0s in which you want to align variable using the string() function. For example `format(2054,string(12-len("HR"),"0"))` would give you "0000002054"

One additional note that I would leave you on is that it's never a good idea to say something like "It is highly unlikely that I would..." and not prepare for it. Murphy's Law is a pain in the B. You should consider handing conditions where you exceed the limit that your key can handle.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Sorry for my "show me the code" comment - it was meant somewhat tongue-in-cheek. I'm starting out with coding, but wouldn't want anyone doing my work for me... just need a bit of a nudge in the right direction (just like what you've given me here for using `format` and `string` to help build my custom key, which is going to be very useful).